# Can I ask users to vote for a tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Suppose there's a tag synonym that was proposed by somebody (not necessarily myself, since I don't yet have the privilege to do so), and I think this synonym should be approved.

I can find the users able to vote for that synonym in the top users of the tag. 
Can I somehow ask them to consider voting for this synonym? Would it be considered an acceptable behavior to do so?

I see tag synonyms that were suggested long ago and didn't get enough votes. I'm not sure the reason for that is that users don't agree to them, because in some cases the synonyms are obvious. Some tags don't have many users eligible to vote for synonyms, and the chance that enough of those who can vote will actually find that there's a suggested synonym waiting for approval seems small.

Or should I just post a synonym request here and wait for a moderator to create it manually?

Comment: +1 - I've wondered that myself, but never bothered to ask.  Curious to see what the answer is.

Comment: Might be interesting if there was some kind of review path where I would be presented with all the synonyms I had sufficient tag-rep to vote on. I think voting on tag synonyms is pretty buried at the moment, and probably doesn't get much traffic.

Comment: How are you going to do that? There's no private message mechanism. Adding such a request as a comment to some question or, worse, as the text of a post, would be an inappropriate usage. I suppose you could catch them in chat. Are you going to track down email addresses for these people?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you may ask other users to review the suggestion and take their votes on it.

Don't ask them to specifically "Vote in favor" or "Vote against this", but rather "Please review this suggestion and vote on it". If it deserves to be approved, it will be.

Comment: @Eran: The best course is to ask them on chat. Assuming there's an appropriate (or at least close) room that can handle the request.

Comment: @Eran: Pretty good. Chat is filled with high reputation users. I'm there too, you can find me in the PHP room most of the time :)

Comment: @Eran: That's why I said, "Assuming there's an appropriate (or at least close) room. That's where you'll find the active users in those tags. If there aren't any. You're reduced to waiting (or posting it here on meta, for a moderator to approve).